# Python: How to extract required information from a string?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Is there a StringTokenizer in Python? Can I do character by character scanning and copying.

I have the following input string

```
data = '123:Palo Alto, CA -> 456:Seattle, WA 789'
```

I need to extract the two (city, state) fields from this string. Here is the code I wrote

```
name_list = []
while i < len(data)):
      if line[i] == ':':
          name = ''
          j = 0
          i = i + 1
          while line[i] != '-' and line[i].isnumeric() == False:
             name[j] = line[i]   # This line gives error
             i = i + 1
             j = j + 1
          name_list.append(name)
      i = i + 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are all cities between a : and a , and these pubctuation appear nowhere else?

Comment: @Mark: I changed the question. I need the (city, state) fields now. Yes these punctuations appear nowhere else

Comment: Is that 789 at the end a typo, or is the pattern non-repeating?

Comment: No its not a typo. Its suppose to signify an arbitrary number :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take, assuming the string is always formatted as per your example:

```
import re

data = '123:Palo Alto, CA -> 456:Seattle, WA 789'

name_list = []
r = re.compile("(\s?\d)|:")
name_list += r.sub("", data).split(" ->")
print name_list # Prints ['Palo Alto, CA', 'Seattle, WA']
```

As a note on your error, the empty string will have a length of 0, so the index 0 doesn't exist:

```
>>> s = ""
>>> len(s)
0
```

You can, however, concatenate strings in Python with the `+` operator, like so:

```
>>> s += "Some"
>>> s += " Text"
>>> print s
Some Text
```

Answer (score 8):

```
data = '123:Palo Alto, CA -> 456:Seattle, WA 789'
citys = []
for record in data.split("->"):
    citys.append(
        re.search(r":(?P<city>[\w\s]+),\s*(?P<state>[\w]+)",record)
        .groupdict()
    )

print citys
```

Gives:

`[{'city': 'Palo Alto', 'state': 'CA'}, {'city': 'Seattle', 'state': 'WA'}]`

Answer (score 3):

You could always use a regular expression, if you wanted: `/\d+:(\w+),\s(\w+)/`.  Its not pretty, but it should get the job done. Assuming string to match is the test string you had.

```
import re

for s in string_to_match.split("->"):
    m = re.match(r"\d+:(\w+),\s(\w+)", s)
    city = m.group(1)
    state = m.group(2)
```

Syntax may be a little off, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you always have the string formatted as shown you could do:

```
cityState = []
for line in data.split('->'):
    cityState.append({'city':city=line.strip().split(',')[0].split(':')[1],
                     'state':state=line.strip().split(',').split(' ')[1]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex. Here is my ugly regex, you can do better

```
inputStr = '123:Palo Alto, CA -> 456:Seattle, WA 789';
m = re.search('.*:(.*),(.*)->.*:(.*),\s*(\S{2})', inputStr)
print "City1=" + m.group(1)
print "State1=" + m.group(2)
print "City2=" + m.group(3)
print "State2=" + m.group(4)
```

Produces

```
City1=Palo Alto
State1= CA 
City2=Seattle
State2=WA
```